# How to refer to valuefield in pivottable VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I refer to pivotfield selected on the screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAEkI.jpg. It is one in values: "Сумм по полю Вес товара, т" (sum of the weight, t).

`.DataLabelRange` doesn't work in this structure

The main goal of the code is to check if such pivotfield exists.
Here is my code:

```
For Each f In p.PivotFields
If f = "Product" Or f.Name = "Export-Import" Then
f.Orientation = xlPageField
ElseIf f.Name = "Company" Or f.Name = "Partner" Then
f.Orientation = xlRowField
ElseIf f.Name = "Weight." Then
f.Orientation = xlDataField
ElseIf f.Name = "USD" Then
f.Orientation = xlDataField
Else f.Orientation <> xlHidden Then
f.Orientation = xlHidden
End If
Next
```

I want to check if this Weight and USD datafield exist. If they are then skip them. Otherwise the code will add the same Datafield again.

Comment: You need to loop on each `PivotFields` to check if that specific field exist.

Comment: What's unsatisfactory in your code now?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways. An easy one would be to use the indirect function. Example `=INDIRECT("B3",TRUE)`